# Line 49, 52,55,58,61,64- 1119:Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type String

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I removed any text from the text box fields so why am I still getting this error ?

Code below :

```
switch (day) {
    case "Sun":
        day.text = "Monday";
    break;
    case "Mom":
        day.text = "Tuesday";
    break;
    case "Tue":
        day.text = "Wednesday";
    break;
    case "Wed":
        day.text = "Thursday";
    break;
    case "Thu":
        day.text = "Friday";
    break;
    case "Fri":
        day.text = "Saturday";
    break;
    case "Sat":
        day.text = "Sunday";
    break;
}

switch (codeToday) {
    case "0":
    case "3200":

        var weather00:weather00 = new weather00();
        _weatherToday.addChild(weather00);
        _weatherToday.scaleX = 10.85;
        _weatherToday.scaleY = 158.75;
        break;

    case "1":
    case "3200":

        var weather01:weather01 = new weather01();
        _weatherToday.addChild(weather01);
        _weatherToday.scaleX = 10.85;
        _weatherToday.scaleY = 158.75;
        break;  
}
```

Comment: This is the code for the lines in question switch (day){
  case "Sun":
      day.text = "Monday";
  break;
  case "Mom":
      day.text = "Tuesday";
  break;
  case "Tue":
      day.text = "Wednesday";
  break;
  case "Wed":
      day.text = "Thursday";
  break;
  case "Thu":
      day.text = "Friday";
  break;
  case "Fri":
      day.text = "Saturday";
  break;
  case "Sat":
      day.text = "Sunday";
  break;
 }

Comment: You are using a `String` var named `day` so you can not use the same name for a `TextField`.

Answer (score 1):

i suppose that 'day' is a **String** variable and have not a text property - look here -> [String](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html)

 Some components have a text property like: [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) and [TextArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html)